# Polling URL and Writing Results to DIV

Tags: jquery

I am polling a URL that queries a JMS queue for some credit card authorization results.  When the URL returns success, I want to write the data to the DIV indicated.

Most of my experience is on the Java back-end.  This is what I've managed to put together so far, but it isn't working.  Nothing shows up in my DIV, even though Chrome and Firebug show that the data are being returned correctly.

Am I making a simple mistake here?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function doPolling() {
            $.ajax({
                url: './poll',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'get',
                success: function(jdata) {
                    console.log(jdata);
                    var jdata = $.parseJSON(jdata);

                    if (jdata.pollerStatus == 'poll-again' && jdata.pollerMessage == 'ok') {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            doPolling();
                        }, 15000);
                    } else if (jdata.pollerStatus == 'done' && jdata.pollerMessage == 'success') {
                        $("#creditcard_results").text(jdata);
                    } else if (jdata.pollerStatus == 'done') {
                        if (jdata.pollerMessage == 'timed out') {
                            $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', false);
                        } else if (jdata.pollerMessage == 'payment-error') {
                            $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', false);
                        } else {
                            $('#submitorder').prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <div id="creditcard_results"></div>
```

Comment: you are going to print JSON inside div?
If you try to use:
$("#creditcard_results").text(jdata.pollerStatus);
instead of $("#creditcard_results").text(jdata);
Will it add to your div text "done"?

Comment: i think your code never reach here `$("#creditcard_results").text(jdata);`

Comment: @MohammadAdil could be right, put console.log() inside your conditionals to see where the failure is

Answer (score 0):

on this line:

```
$("#creditcard_results").text(jdata);
```

jdata is an object. The .text() function only takes a string or callback function that returns a string.